# Django Admin hangs with nginx port 443

Tags: python, django, ssl, nginx, gunicorn

I want to setup django with nginx and gunicorn with https. But if I want to go to admin of django it hangs with loading.

I call the app with the following command:
**gunicorn core.wsgi:application --bind 127.0.0.1:8181 --certfile=/etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt --keyfile=/etc/nginx/ssl/hoi.key**

And I've already in my settings.py:

- CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
- SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
- SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

And this is my nginx configuration:

```
server{
listen   80;
listen 443 ssl;
server_name test.hello.com;
access_log /var/log/nginx/neat.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/neat.error.log;
root /var/www/Test/;
ssl on; 
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/hoi.key;
ssl_session_timeout 5m;
ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
location / 
{
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8181;          
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    client_max_body_size 10m;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're informing django how to detect if request is done via https, but you don't have proper header set in your nginx file. Try to add:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

into location section in nginx config.

Also, you don't have to estabilish secured connection between gunicorn and nginx. They are communicating in localhost and there is nothing that could potentially sniff that communication (except of stuff on your own server, but those able to sniff localhost connection, can also access your certs and decrypt https). If you want to set that connection secured (because for example not only you have access to that server), use unix sockets and proper access rights.

Comment: It is by your comment now I understand. Now it works!! So many thanks. You help me out, because I was almost stuck for 3 days. Big thumbs up! :-)